Combining two arrays in a pipeline in Azure Data Factory
As part of an Azure Data Factory pipeline, I have created two arrays (both have integer values):
[value1, value2, value3]
and
[value4, value5, value6]
I want to combine these two arrays into:
[[value1, value4], [value2, value5], [value3, value6]]
Basically zipping them together. I want to do this so that I can pass the array to a ForLoop with each item being in this case [value1, value4], [value2, value5], and [value3, value6]. Then I can pass the values in each pair to the appropriate parameter in a dataset.
On top of this both of the original arrays need to be sorted in ascending order before zipping for this to work so I need a way to sort and then zip these variables.
Is it possible to do this in ADF? Any ideas appreciated!

Are the values in the arrays strings or integers? And do you want the inner arrays to be sorted or total array?

Hi I've made some edits to my original question for clarity. Hope this helps!

Do you need this only in ADF pipeline? or can you use Dataflow?


but not how to get the arrays from variables (these are calculated in the pipeline), to the data flow, then back to a variable in the pipeline.

You can make use of the Mapping dataflow parameters and pass your array variables from pipeline to the dataflow via the parameters.
First create the required parameters of integer array type without any default value in the dataflow.

Now, come to the dataflow activity in the pipeline and pass your array variables to the dataflow using Pipeline dynamic expression as shown below.

In the dataflow, create a source with a dummy csv dataset. The csv file should container at least one column and one row as shown below which will be removed later in the dataflow.

After source, take a Derived column transformation and create a new column res_array and use below expression to generate the required array using the parameters.
mapIndex(sort($arr1,compare(#item1,#item2)),array(#item,sort($arr2,compare(#item1,#item2))[#index]))


Next, this array needs to be sent back to the pipeline. For that, you need to use sink cache in the dataflow. Add sink and select Cache and also check the Write to activity output so that the column value will be sent in the dataflow activity output.

To remove the extra column from the dummy source, go to the sink mapping and uncheck the Auto mapping and then remove the extra column.

In the dataflow activity, set the logging to None and uncheck the First row only option.

Upon running the dataflow activity, it will give the required array in the dataflow activity output like below.

You can use this array in your pipeline later on by using the below expression after the dataflow activity.
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.<your_sink_name>.value


Great, this has worked! Thanks so much!! :) Do you mind explaining what the mapIndex code does briefly? Thanks

mapIndex() function will loop through the item and indexes of an array which is given to it and you can modify the item as per your requirement. I have given a sorted arr1 as array and modified each item as a sub array of values from two arrays. When selecting the value from arr2 I have used sort on it so that both arrays will be sorted before generating the required array.

You can go through this doc to know about the expressions in the ADF mapping dataflow.

Great thank you! :)

Since ADF pipeline expressions do not support array sorting directly, you'll need to use a Mapping Data Flow to sort the arrays.

Read your arrays into the data flow. If your arrays are stored in files or databases, set up appropriate datasets to read them.
Add a Sort transformation for each array to sort them in ascending order based on their values.
After sorting each array, add a Surrogate Key transformation to assign a row number to each element. This will help in zipping the arrays later.
Join the two sorted streams on their surrogate keys (row numbers) using a Join.
Select the required columns from both arrays.
Output the joined data to a sink


Thank you for this! I feel confident being able to transform the data once it's in the data flow but not how to get the arrays from variables (these are calculated in the pipeline), to the data flow, then back to a variable in the pipeline. Do you mind going into more detail on this please? Thanks :)
